# jquery empty() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

I'm completely new to jquery - so apologies for any stupidity. Boiled down, my problem is quite simple:

I have html code:

```
<div class="v" align="center" id="div4">
 <div id="div5" class="h blurb">
  <span style="font-size:20px;">
   <div id="text">DISAPPEAR PLEASE</div>
  </span>
 </div>
 <y>
  <div class="exit">
  </div>
 </y>
</div>
```

When I click the "y" button, I want the "DISAPPEAR PLEASE" text to clear. So I'm using a bit of jquery:

```
 $("y").click(function(){
    $("#text").empty();

 })
```

...which doesn't work. It does work if I substitute in "#div5" instead - but obviously that removes the span and #text div too, which I need to remain. I've spent hours on this: how can I empty just the blimming #text div?? Thanks for any help...

Comment: What is `y`? That is not a valid HTML tag.

Comment: What are you trying to hide? Which elements?

Comment: works here: http://jsfiddle.net/VMdg7/  But what is supposed to be Y tag?

Comment: Where are you adding the jQuery  code?

Comment: Are you including jQuery? Are you calling your jQuery within a document ready handler or at the end of your page?

Comment: In your click call back, include something like `alert('click');` or `console.log('click');` so you know at least this part is working.

Comment: Use either `hide()` or `$("#text").css('display','none')`

Comment: `<y>` is a perfectly valid tag, this isn't 2006

Answer (score 6):

I know it's an old thread, but maybe still some people who find this are interested. The problem is that `.empty()` removes *child* elements of #text, and not #text itself. Therefore `.remove()` should be used instead.

Comment: Or, just simply `$('#text').val('')`

Comment: No, `.val('')` applies to HTML attribute `value`, that's just for `<input>`. It should be `$('#text').text('')`.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine. There's something else going wrong. If the issue is specific to a browser you should try creating the element with `document.createElement('y')`, kind of how the HTML5 shiv allows HTML5 elements in old IE.

My very simple demo of `$('foo').empty()` worked just fine in Chrome: http://jsbin.com/iNESoTad/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: How is this an answer? "There's something else going wrong." Really?

Comment: They're accusing `.empty()` of not working. Just letting them know it's not `.empty()` that's causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone - it now works fine for me too: I'm not sure why it wasn't working, as I tried it numerous times. I was hoping that that would solve a bigger problem which  it hasn;t though, so I may repost that in a separate thread!

Comment: @j08691: http://www.nptelegraph.com/news/something-went-wrong-in-plane-crash-expert-says/article_bc5efd9b-a8b1-5e0c-9a4b-4da4769b54a8.html

Answer (score 0):

Jquery's `empty()` method removes nodes, not the actual content, which is why it works on the parent `div`. Try setting the text (`.text()`) or the html (`.html()`) of the `div` to an empty string.
Also, it's bad practice to include a `div` inside of a `span`, so you might want to rethink the nesting there.

[Source (Jquery API)](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Comment: This is not the problem. OP tries to manipulate a `y` DOM Element which is invalid.

Comment: I actually figured the "y" bit was a typo. Assuming that, replacing the .empty() with .text() or .html() and using an empty string (which also reflects his intention better, I think) makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure about `y` tag? try to remove it, instead use

```
 $(".exit").click(function(){
    $("#text").empty();

 })
```

and set width and height for `div.exit` to create click area.